# Create XSLT for XML from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have to convert XML to another XML through XSL. I have following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SKOS xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:skosxl="http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#">
    <skos:descriptor ID="7769" TAGNO="111" ISVALID="true">
        <skos:altLabel>ABYSSINIAN Expedition (1867-1868)</skos:altLabel>
        <skos:prefLabel>Abyssinian Expedition (1867-1868)</skos:prefLabel>
        <skos:broader>Ethiopia -- History -- 1490-1889</skos:broader>
        <skos:broader>Great Britain -- History -- Victoria, 1837-1901</skos:broader>
        <skosxl:hiddenLabel>Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</skosxl:hiddenLabel>
        <skosxl:hiddenLabel>British Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</skosxl:hiddenLabel>
        <skosxl:hiddenLabel>Magdala Campaign, 1867-1868</skosxl:hiddenLabel>
        <skosxl:hiddenLabel>Napier Expedition, 1867-1868</skosxl:hiddenLabel>
    </skos:descriptor>
</SKOS>
```

and I want output like this

```
<add>
<doc>
    <field name="id">7769</field>
    <field name="TAGNO">111</field>
    <field name="altLabel">ABYSSINIAN Expedition (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="broader">Ethiopia -- History -- 1490-1889</field>
    <field name="broader">Great Britain -- History -- Victoria, 1837-1901</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">British Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Magdala Campaign, 1867-1868</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Napier Expedition, 1867-1868</field>

</doc>
```

I am not getting how to make XSLT of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided no explanation about how that input results in that output (e.g. why is there no `ISVALID` field in the output? Is `ISVALID` relevant to this process or should it be ignored? Why is there no `prefLabel` field in the output?), but this will produce the output you described:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
                exclude-result-prefixes="skos"
               >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <add>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:descriptor" />
    </add>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="skos:descriptor">
    <doc>
      <field name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </field>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name() = 'ID' or name() = 'ISVALID')] | 
                                   *[not(self::skos:prefLabel)]" />
    </doc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | *">
    <field name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </field>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">7769</field>
    <field name="TAGNO">111</field>
    <field name="altLabel">ABYSSINIAN Expedition (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="broader">Ethiopia -- History -- 1490-1889</field>
    <field name="broader">Great Britain -- History -- Victoria, 1837-1901</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">British Expedition to Abyssinia (1867-1868)</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Magdala Campaign, 1867-1868</field>
    <field name="hiddenLabel">Napier Expedition, 1867-1868</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            String st = "Your Xml";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(st);
            XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(st));
            string Xml = "<doc>";
            while (read.Read())
            {
                if (read.AttributeCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < read.AttributeCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (read.Name == "xml" || read.Name.Split(':').Count() < 2)
                            break;
                        var node = doc.GetElementsByTagName(read.Name);
                        Xml += "<field name=\"" + node[0].Attributes[i].Name + "\">" + node[0].Attributes[i].Value + "</field>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (read.Name != string.Empty && read.Name.Split(':').Count() > 1)
                        Xml += "<field name=\"" + read.LocalName + "\">" + read.ReadInnerXml() + "</field>";
                }
            }
            Xml += "</doc>";
```